# How to parse values with AWK when column number is inconsistent

Tags: parsing, awk, bioinformatics

Input file:

```
6       31236622        HLA_C*05:01:01:01       A       T       .       PASS    AF=0.07724;MAF=0.07724;R2=0.98466;IMPUTED       GT:DS:HDS:GP    1|0:0.999:0.999,0.000:0.001,0.999,0.000 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 1|1:1.994:0.995,1.000:0.000,0.006,0.994
6       29910248        HLA_A*01:01     A       T       .       PASS    AF=0.15969;MAF=0.15969;R2=0.97333;IMPUTED       GT:DS:HDS:GP    0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 1|0:1.000:1.000,0.000:0.000,1.000,0.000 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 
6       31322134        HLA_B*55:01     A       T       .       PASS    AF=0.01091;MAF=0.01091;R2=0.94511;IMPUTED       GT:DS:HDS:GP    0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0
6       31322132        HLA_B*55        A       T       .       PASS    AF=0.01091;MAF=0.01091;R2=0.94485;IMPUTED       GT:DS:HDS:GP    0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0
6       31322006        HLA_B*44:02:01:01       A       T       .       PASS    AF=0.08074;MAF=0.08074;R2=0.97706;IMPUTED       GT:DS:HDS:GP    1|0:0.999:0.999,0.000:0.001,0.999,0.000 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 1|1:1.997:0.998,0.999:0.000,0.003,0.997
```

**I want to parse a specific number from each column after the "GT:DS:HDS:GP" column, specifically, the numbers after "x|x:". So desired output is:**

```
0.999, 0, 1.994
0, 1.000, 0
0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0
0.999, 0, 1.997
```

To parse the desired values from (e.g.) line 4, I can use:

```
awk -F: '{for (i=5; i<=NF; i+=3) printf "%s%s", $i, (i+3 <= NF ? ", " : ORS)}'
```

Line 5 would require:

```
awk -F: '{for (i=9; i<=NF; i+=3) printf "%s%s", $i, (i+3 <= NF ? ", " : ORS)}'
```

So the problem with the input file is that column 3 (space delimited) contains a variable number of colons, which makes colons a poor delimiter for this particular input file (but the desired values are surrounded by colons!)

I though about using "|" as delimiter, with substr($i,3,?), but the desired values have an inconsistent number of digits (hence the "?").

Is there a flexible awk code to get the desired output?

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, could you please highlight sample output to be more clear, thank you.

Comment: this is a job for `bcftools query`

Comment: @Pierre I would really like to know how to parse these dosages with bcftools. Can you elaborate/ provide code? Thanks

Comment: (not tested) `bcftools query -u -f '[%DS %HDS %GP]\n'`

Comment: Yes, as @Pierre suggested use the right tool to manipulate VCF files, here is my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59104151/680068 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/54305323/680068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
awk -v OFS=', ' '$9 == "GT:DS:HDS:GP" {for (i=10; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i ~ /^[0-9]+\|[0-9]+:/ && split($i, a, /:/)) printf "%s", (i == 10 ? "" : OFS) a[2]; print ""}' file

0.999, 0, 1.994
0, 1.000, 0
0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0
0.999, 0, 1.997
```

An expanded form:

```sh
awk -v OFS=', ' '
$9 == "GT:DS:HDS:GP" {
   for (i=10; i<=NF; ++i)
      if ($i ~ /^[0-9]+\|[0-9]+:/ && split($i, a, /:/))
         printf "%s", (i == 10 ? "" : OFS) a[2]
   print ""
}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you care about the space-delimited columns at all?

```sh
awk '{ sub(/.* GT:DS:HDS:GP */, "");
    i = split($0, n, /[0-9]\|[0-9]:/);
    sep = "";
    for(x=2; x<=i; x++) {
        sub(/:.*/, "", n[x]); printf("%s%s", sep, n[x]); sep=", " }
    printf "\n"; }' file
```

We successively pick apart each line, first by removing everything through `GT:DS:HDS:GP` from the line, then by splitting the remaining string into `n` on the specified delimiter, and then cleaning up the resulting fields by removing everything after the first colon in each, and printing the result. (We skip the first one, which only contains the useless short or empty string before the first delimiter.)

Output for your sample:

```
0.999, 0, 1.994
0, 1.000, 0
0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0
0.999, 0, 1.997
```

I have no idea what these fields stands for so I just picked single-letter variable names; you can probably improve the readability by giving these variables more descriptive names.